# Android: MapView showing only gray grid with the error "Couldn't get connection factory client"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

For the past few days I've been having trouble getting a simple MapView working, no overlays nothing, just the map. I've looked up a lot of solutions but none of them worked for me.

I have a apikey for the debug keystore. I have all the proper permissions in their proper places in the manifest file, but I'm still getting the same error and the same gray grid. Is there something I'm missing in my code? I don't know what is going wrong, please help!

This is the layout xml for the mapactivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="xxxx" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the mapactivity code:

```
public class MapActivity extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_view);  
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        .
        .
        .
        .   
        <activity android:name="MapActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This usually means an error with your signing key.  Have you registered your certificate key with google?  If yes, make sure that you sign with release key when running on the device and with the debug key when running on the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes and yes. I registered my key with google and I'm using the right key.

Comment: I just generated a new debug.keystore, but still the same error :(

Comment: When you generate a new debug.keystore, you get a new key.  Now you need to register that key with Google.  Have a look at this page: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html - and then follow the instructions starting with "Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate".

Comment: I did so when I generated the new keystore...didn't help

Comment: Same issue here. Two keys generated (debug and release) but google stays gray in signed APK. Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

By using SHA1 Certificate fingerprints i have got the same problem.So i have gone for MD5 Certificate fingerprints. Go to this site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup and give you MD5 fingerprints and get the key.
 to get the MD5 fingerprints

1. Open your command prompt by typing cmd in your run. Start ⇒ Run ⇒ type cmd
2. Go to jdk's bin directory by typing cd c:\path-to-jdk-dir\bin\
   In my case i typed cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\
3. then type keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
       "C:\Users\user-name.android\debug.keystore" -list -v

   In my case i typed keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\User.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
4. Then you will be asked for a password. default password is android.
5. then you will get the MD5 Fingerprint.

Comment: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version.